# Align buttons from top to bot on smaller screens

Tags: html, css, laravel, responsive-design, tailwind-css

I am in the midst of making my project responsive, and for this I want to align buttons which are normally next to each other align from top to bot when the screen gets smaller.

This are the buttons at the moment:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7a46.png

This is the code for them:

```
<form class="mb-5 flex justify-left grid grid-cols-4 gap-x-20">
.
.
. 
</form>
```

I am using tailwind css and tried adding css code like `sm:grid sm:grid-rows-4` - and then adding for every button something like this: `sm:row-start-1`
but then also on normal screen size there is a huge space generated between the buttons and the content beneath it.

Any input appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know how to do it in basic CSS
Add this class(change the name if required) to your form

```
.form {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;  <!-- To make them aligned vertically -->
justify-content: space-evenly;  <!-- To make them spaced evenly -->

}
```

Add this class(change the name if required) to you buttons

```
.button {
padding: 10px 20px;  <!-- Change the padding to your liking -->
}
```

To make them align vertically when screen size is suppose 600px

```
@media (max-width:600px)  <!-- To make them aligned vertically till the width of the screen is 600px -->
 {
.form {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;  <!-- To make them aligned vertically -->
justify-content: space-evenly;  <!-- To make them spaced evenly -->
}
.button {
padding: 10px 20px;  <!-- Change the padding to your liking -->
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer! Sadly with this css they are aligned from top to bot all the time

Comment: It worked perfectly!!! :D thanks a lot! didn't even think about using "normal" CSS with tailwind lol, such a nice and simple solution :)